# lock is acquired indefinitely and not releasing

Tags: java, alfresco

I have written the below method to avoid concurrency.but when we deploy the code in lower envs(DEV,QA) its working fine But not in PROD because data is huge there and multiple servers will access this code concurrently, when we analyzed using Thread profiler, lock is not releasing and struck at isActive() method at line:27 indifinetely and its taking lot of CPU time and Memory..

Is there any way to modify the code?

```
public void registerToken(NodeRef nodeRef)
    throws IdenticalContentException
  {
    final AtomicBoolean stillRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    String lockToken = null;
    String nodeRefToken = getToken(nodeRef);

    try
    {
      lockToken = this.jobLockService.getLock(getLock(nodeRefToken), 30000L, 3000L, 2);

      JobLockService.JobLockRefreshCallback callback = new JobLockService.JobLockRefreshCallback()
      {
        public void lockReleased()
        {
          stillRunning.set(false);
        }

        public boolean isActive()
        {
          return stillRunning.get();
        }
      };
      this.jobLockService.refreshLock(lockToken, getLock(nodeRefToken), 30000L, callback);
      if (stillRunning.get()) {
        registerNode(nodeRef, nodeRefToken);
      }
    }
    catch (LockAcquisitionException lae)
    {
      LOG.error("Failed to acquire a lock for metadata checking", lae);
      throw lae;
    }
    finally
    {
      stillRunning.set(false);
      if (lockToken != null) {
        this.jobLockService.releaseLock(lockToken, getLock(nodeRefToken));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is `getLock(nodeRefToken)` returning the same thing every time you call it? What about if you keep that in a variable, so you can use it again in the finally?

Comment: .so it will generate same token[getToken(nodeRef)] for the same nodeRef. after that This is what getLock method does. private QName getLock(String noderef)
  {
    return QName.createQName("http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0", "Token-" + noderef);
  }

Comment: What is this snippet trying to do?

Comment: which snippet of code?